# JavaScript Mobile Applications Abilities

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

anyone knows what are the abilities of HTML-CSS-JavaScript mobile applications (android apps) rather than animations ? what about web access and such things ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is being very powerful language especially when we are taking about mobile applications and spa (single page applications). It can be used to load web views via ajax requests and more, it supports device APIs that allow a mobile app developer to access native device function such as the camera or accelerometer from JavaScript libraries , for example [cordova](http://cordova.apache.org) . Cordova is the most known library that gives you that power.

In addition to that you can use libraries to make your application look like mobile native apps and enrich your application with functionalities (form validation , navigation, and more), examples : [sencha](http://www.sencha.com) or [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com)  .....